# hiding DIV when clicking away from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im basically trying to make a simple dropdown menu with html, css and jquery
and im having trouble with closing the div when a user clicks away from it.

i've tried stopPropagation and binding an action to the document when clicked, they either do not work or I have no idea how to use them. anyway have a look at the code below

**HTML**

```
<div id="optionsMenu">
   <a href="account.php?edit=info">Account Settings</a>    
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.options').click(function(){
   if($('#optionsMenu').css("display") == 'none'){
      $('#optionsMenu').slideDown("fast");
   }

   else{
      $('#optionsMenu').slideUp("fast");
   }
});

$('#optionsMenu').blur(function(){
   $('#optionsMenu').css("display","none");
});
```

any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use stopPropagation:

```
$(body).click(function(e)
{
   $('#optionsMenu').slideUp('fast');
});
$('#optionsMenu').click(function(e)
{
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I liked your answer because it was simple and its easy to understand

Answer (score 3):

You could use `on()`, perhaps:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    if ($(e.target).not('#optionsMenu')){
        $('#optionsMenu').slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

The above not yet tested, but should, I think work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this just makes the menu slide down then slide up again, so its not what im looking for.

Comment: Yes, you've still got use `e.stopPropagation();` in the event-handler that shows the `#optionsMenu`. See the demo.